# Map values based on remaining time

Tags: mysql, join, window

I have two data sets one storing projected values and one storing actual data. I have to update the actual data based on weeks from projected data. If the actual week exceeds the projected week then updated the actual week data with difference of total projected week

example

```
Table Projected             Table Actual            Desired Column to be mapped
Product WeekP   Value       Product WeekA   Value   Update Value From WeekP
 A       1       0.4         A      1        0.4             1
 A       2       0.6         A      2        0.6             2
 A       3       0.8         A      3        0.8             3
 A       4        1          A      4         1              4
 A       5       1.2         A      5        1.2             5
 A       6       1.4         A      6        1.4             6
                             A      7        0.8             3
                             A      8         1              4
                             A      9        1.2             5
                             A     10        1.4             6
```

I'm able to update the first 6 week of data from WeekP to WeekA using a simple join. The difficulty is to dynamically lookup how may weeks are still reaming and update from last week of WeekP going back. Any help on this is appreciated.

Result

```
Product WeekA   WeekP ValueP
A         1       1    0.4
A         2       2    0.6
A         3       3    0.8
A         4       4    1
A         5       5    1.2
A         6       6    1.4
A         7       3    0.8
A         8       4    1
A         9       5    1.2
A         10      6    1.4
```

Comment: Show us what is your expected result. I doubt you want a list of number for your result?

Comment: Why `WeekA = 7` is mapped to `WeekP = 3`  ??

Comment: Its the total week remiang for WeekA

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Its the total week remaining for WeekA , so 1-6 we have values from Week P, now we check how many weeks are remaining  in week A to be updated. Since there are  4 weeks remaining (7-10) we get the last for weeks of data again from week P in asc order.

Comment: Sorry would keep in mind to do so for future questions, should i repost the question in a proper format?

Comment: what if you have 20 weeks? then what result you expect?

Comment: Just edit this one. Dont put table side by side. Because is harder to copy paste and create the sample db